# YARD: How to generate vendor plugin documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, documentation, yard

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and the [YARD 0.7.4](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md) gem for documentation purposes. I implemented a working plugin (in the `ROOT_APP/vendor/plugins/<plugin_name>` directory) and *I would like to document that plugin*.

*Note*: When I run the `yard doc` Terminal command from the root directory of my application in order to generate documentation files, the YARD gem doesn't generate the documentation related to my plugin (all other documentation files are properly generated).

So, **is it possible to document plugins? If so, how can I make that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert that into a gem, with which you can use yard. Vendor plugins are going to be deprecated in 3.2:

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released